# Where's the ol.js (full build of library) from open layers 6v documentation on 9v?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6, index.html

Trying to develop my fist web aplication, i just downloaded the 9v open layers files to build it. As suggested by ssome tutorials that were using openlayers 6v, instructor were connecting ol.js from the folder downloaded on open layers page to index.html that was being created. Open layers folder are not with the 4 main archives, the folder is coming with a bunch of files. Anyone can help?

Which folder or archive should imention on index.html file

Comment: Script and css links are shown on https://openlayers.org/download/